# Properties of the norm of a multi-dimensional kernel

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a Dirac probability measure on finite points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (i.e., $\mu = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{x_i}$), and let $K_{i,j}:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function for $1\leq i,j\leq m$, so that $K(x,y)$ is an $m\times m$ matrix for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We assume that $K(x,y)^T = K(y,x)$, and if necessary, additionally assume that $K_{ij}(x,y) = g_i(x)g_j(y)$ for some function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

Now let us denote $\mathscr{F}$ by the class of measurable functions $f$ such that $E_{x\sim \mu} (||f(x)||_2^2) \leq 1$, and define $C:=sup_{f\in \mathscr{R}} E_{x,y\sim \mu}[f(x)^TK(x,y)f(y)]$ where $x,y$ are sample independently.

Define $T_K(f):=E_{x\sim \mu}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m \big(E_{y\sim \mu}[\sum_{j=1}^m f_i(y) K_{ij}(x,y)]\big)^2\bigg]$ for $f\in \mathscr{F}$.

Then, how do I show that $\sup_{f\in \mathscr{F}} T_K(f) = C$?

The reference I am reading says that if $x_1,...,x_N$ are the support points of $\mu$, these two constants are equal to the maximum eigenvalue of the $nm\times nm$ matrix $K_{ab}(x_i,x_j)$, but I am not sure how to derive this.

===

Picking $f\in\mathscr{F}$, we have that

\begin{align}
T_K(f) &= E_{x\sim \mu}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m \big(E_{y\sim \mu}[\langle f(y), K_{i,\cdot}(x,y)\rangle]\big)^2\bigg] \\
&\leq E_{x\sim \mu}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m E_{y\sim \mu}(||f(y)||_2^2)\cdot E_{y\sim \mu}(||K_{i,\cdot}(x,y)||_2^2)\bigg] \\
&\leq E_{x\sim \mu}\bigg[\sum_{i=1}^m E_{y\sim \mu}(||K_{i,\cdot}(x,y)||_2^2)\bigg] \\
&= E_{x,y\sim \mu} \bigg[ \sum_{i,j=1}^m K_{ij}^2(x,y) \bigg].
\end{align}

Analogously, we can show that $C\leq E_{x,y\sim \mu} \bigg[ \sum_{i,j=1}^m K_{ij}^2(x,y) \bigg]$.

Therefore, both $\sup_{f\in\mathscr{F}} T_K(f)$ and $C$ are bounded by $E_{x,y\sim \mu} \bigg[ \sum_{i,j=1}^m K_{ij}^2(x,y) \bigg]$, but I am not sure how to derive the relation between these two constants..

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does $E_{x \sim \mu}$ mean?

Comment: From context, it seems to mean $E_{x\sim \mu}(f) = \langle f, \mu \rangle = \int f d\mu.$ Obviously then, $E_{x,y\sim \mu}(f)$ with "where $x,y$ are sample[d] independently" really means $\langle f, \mu \otimes \mu \rangle = \int f(x,y) d(\mu \otimes \mu)(x,y).$

Comment: I haven't checked closely, but - take $g_i(x) = 1$ for each $i$ and $x$. Let $S(f) = \mathbb{E}_{\mu \otimes \mu}[f(x)^T K(x,y) f(y)].$ Then $S(f) = \mathbb{E}[\langle f, \mathbf{1}\rangle]^2$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the all ones vector. Observe that $T(f) = \mathbb{E}_{x}[ \sum_{i = 1}^m (\mathbb{E}_y[ m f_i(y)])^2] = m^2 \sum_{i = 1}^m \mathbb{E}_y[f_i(y)^2],$ and so $\sup T(f) = m^2$. On the other hand, $S(f) \le m\mathbb{E}[\|f\|_2]^2 \le m.$ Can you re-check the expressions in the source for $T(f)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too long for a comment. Some observations only.**

If $K = g g^\intercal$ as you suggest adding, and $\mu$ is concentrated in a single point $x_0,$ say (so that $N = 1),$ then
$$
C = \sup\limits_{\| f\|_{\mathscr{L}^2_{\mathbf{R}^m} (\mathbf{R}^n; \mu) \leq 1}} \int f(x)^\intercal g(x) g(y)^\intercal f(y) d(\mu \otimes \mu)(x,y) = \sup\limits_{\| f\|_{\mathscr{L}^2_{\mathbf{R}^m} (\mathbf{R}^n; \mu) \leq 1}} \Big( f(x_0)^\intercal g(x_0) \Big)^2.
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align*}
T_K(f) &= \int d\mu(x) \sum_{i = 1}^m \left\{ \int d\mu(y) \sum_{j = 1}^m f_i(y) g_i(x) g_j(y) \right\}^2 \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^m \left\{ \sum_{j = 1}^m f_i(x_0) g_i(x_0) g_j(x_0) \right\}^2 \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^m f_i(x_0)^2g_i(x_0)^2 \left\{ \sum_{j = 1}^m g_j(x_0) \right\}^2.
\end{align*}
$$
So, there seems there is no equality at all. In fact, it seems that one will get $\|T_K\| = C^2.$

Comment: I have just verified that the equality $||T_K|| = C^2$ holds in general. The argument is basically identical to your answer. However, for "not-singleton" supports, just use the identification $f(x)$ as the $N\times m$ vector $(f_1(x_1),\cdots, f_m(x_1), \cdots, f_1(x_N),\cdots,f_m(x_N))$.

Comment: @Rubertos I'd be interested in reading the solution. Do you mind posting it?

Comment: Define the matrix $A$ as $$\begin{bmatrix}K(x_1,x_1)&\cdots & K(x_1,x_N)\\\cdots&\cdots & \cdots \\ K(x_N,x_1)&\cdots & K(x_N,x_N)\end{bmatrix}$$. Since $K(x,y)^T = K(y,x)$, this matrix is symmetric. Now, note that $E_y(\langle f(y), K_{i,\cdot}(x_l,y)\rangle) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^m f_i(x_k)K_{ij}(x_l,x_k) = \frac{1}{N} (A\bar{f})_{m(l-1) +i}$, where $\bar{f}$ is the $N\times m$ vector under the correspondence I mentioned in the comment above. By directly arranging it again, we get $T_K(f) = \frac{1}{N^3} ||A\bar{f}||_2^2$.